# Cookie saved without content and expiration

Tags: asp.net, cookies

I'm working on an ASP .NET project and trying to save a cookie.
My browser (chrome) displays the cookie but without its content and the expiration date is until the end of the session.
Below is my code:

```
HttpCookie facebookID = new HttpCookie("facebookID");
facebookID.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(12);
facebookID.Value = Request.QueryString["id"].ToString(); //Querystring returns value
Response.Cookies.Add(facebookID);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the cookie in ASP.Net like this :

```
 Response.Cookies["facebookID"].Value = Request.QueryString["id"].ToString();
 Response.Cookies["facebookID"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(30);
```

and you call the cookie like this :

```
     if (Request.Cookies["facebookID"] != null)
        {
            var facebookid = Request.Cookies["facebookID"].Value; 
        }
```

and you can delete the cookie like this :

```
Response.Cookies["facebookID"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-30);
```

here is a good article on storing cookies in ASP.Net [Cookie in ASP.Net](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/244904/Cookies-in-ASP-NET)

Comment: Yes I know this one..My code is similar to the first example there